# How can I replace JSON Converter with my own

Tags: json, grails, jackson

I'm looking to use JACKSON instead of grails JSON ,without changing the auto-scaffolded contollers.

Is it possible to seamlessly replace the current grails JSON converter with another one ?

Are there any classes to implement other then AbstractConverter...

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple. AbstractConverter is all you need to extend to do:

```
render result as JackSON
```

Something like this***:
*** taken from here: https://github.com/sjhorn/grails-jackson/blob/master/src/groovy/com/hornmicro/JackSON.groovy

```
class JackSON extends AbstractConverter {
    Object target

    public JackSON() {

    }

    public JackSON(Object target) {
        this()
        setTarget(target)
    }

    public void render(Writer out) throws ConverterException {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper() 
            mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
            mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.FLUSH_PASSED_TO_STREAM, false) 
            mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_JSON_CONTENT, false)
            mapper.writeValue(out, target)
        } catch(e) {
            throw new ConverterException(e)
        } 

        try {
            out.flush()
            out.close()
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Unexpected exception while closing a writer: " + e.getMessage())
        }
    }

    public void render(HttpServletResponse response) throws ConverterException {
        response.setContentType(GrailsWebUtil.getContentType("application/json", "UTF-8"));
        try {
            render(response.getWriter())
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(e)
        }
    }

    public Object getWriter() throws ConverterException {
        throw new ConverterException("Not Implemented")
    }

    public void convertAnother(Object o) throws ConverterException {
        throw new ConverterException("Not Implemented")
    }

    public void build(Closure c) throws ConverterException {
        throw new ConverterException("Not Implemented")
    }

    public ObjectMarshaller lookupObjectMarshaller(Object target) {
        return null
    }

    public void setTarget(Object target) {
        this.target = target
    }
}
```

Comment: hi as i said i am not looking to change my controllers code, just whenever JSON is used, then use JACKSON instead, like an interceptor before JSON is used